# Caching active record associations with fresh_when

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

What's the best way to cache ActiveRecord associations? Here's what I am trying to do in the controller:

```
def all_posts
  @posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts
  fresh_when @posts
end
```

Whenever a new post is added to the `user` model I need to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solution works perfect.

In case you are just adding posts there is a more performant solution: You'll have to had a `touch: true` to the `belongs_to :user` part of your `Post` model. ActiveRecord will touch the User object every time a post gets changed and a new post gets created. When you have that implemented you can use this controller code:

```
def all_posts
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = user.posts
  fresh_when user
end
```

It is much faster to generate a cache key from one `user` than from many `posts`.

Have a look at http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/caching.html to get an introduction to caching in Rails.